# Connect Login to the Main Class (Object Oriented)

Tags: java, oop

Here's my Login class:

```
        package mangInasal;

    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class MILogin extends JFrame {

        private JLabel lblUsername, lblPassword;
        private JTextField txtUsername;
        private JPasswordField txtPassword;
        private JButton btnLogin, btnCancel;

        public MILogin() {

            super("Login");
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            lblUsername = new JLabel("Username: ");
            add(lblUsername);

            txtUsername = new JTextField(10);
            add(txtUsername);

            lblPassword = new JLabel("Password: ");
            add(lblPassword);

            txtPassword = new JPasswordField(10);
            add(txtPassword);

            btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
            add(btnLogin);

            btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
            add(btnCancel);

            ActionListener listener = new ButtonListener();
            btnLogin.addActionListener(listener);
            btnCancel.addActionListener(listener);

        }

        private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
                String username = txtUsername.getText().toUpperCase();
                String pass = txtPassword.getText();

                if (source == btnLogin) {

                    if (username.equals("TIPQC") && (pass.equals("ABET"))) {
                        String okay = "defimages/loginsuccess.gif";
                        java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(okay);
                        ImageIcon okpic = new ImageIcon(imgURL);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WELCOME", "Correct Input", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, okpic);
                        dispose();
                        mangInasaldef manginasaldef = new mangInasaldef();
                        manginasaldef.run();

                    } else {
                        String okay = "defimages/loginfail.gif";
                        java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(okay);
                        ImageIcon failpic = new ImageIcon(imgURL);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Username or Password", "Message Dialog", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, failpic);
                    }

                }

                if (source == btnCancel) {

                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }

        public void run() {

            setSize(200, 200);
            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setResizable(false);



        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            MILogin milogin = new MILogin();
            milogin.run();

        }
    }
```

And here's my Main class:

```
    package mangInasal;

import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class mangInasaldef  extends JFrame{ //class name

      private static String username  = "";
      private static String customername  = "";
      private static String dineOut  = "";
      private String order = "";
      private String order1 = "";
      private String order2 = "";
      private String order3 = "";
      private String order4 = "";
      private String order5 = "";
      private String order6 = "";
      private String order7 = "";
      private String order8 = "";
      private String order9 = "";
      private String order10 = "";
      private String order11 = "";
      private String order12 = "";
      private String order13 = "";
      private String order14 = "";
      private String order15 = "";
      private String order16 = "";
      private String order17 = "";
       private int total = 0;
       private int totalSpicy = 0; 
       private int total1 = 0;
        private int total2= 0;
        private int total3 = 0;
        private int total4 = 0;
        private int total5 = 0;
        private int total6 = 0;
        private int total7 = 0;
        private int total8 = 0;
        private int total9 = 0;
        private int total10 = 0;
        private int total11 = 0;
        private int total12 = 0;
        private int total13 = 0;
        private int total14 = 0;
        private int total15 = 0;
        private int total16 = 0;
        private int total17 = 0;
      private int totalOrder = total + totalSpicy + total1 + total2 + total3 + total4 + total5 + total6 + total7 + total8 + total9 + total10 + total11 + total12 + total13 + total14 + total15;
      private double vatCollected = totalOrder * 0.12;
      private boolean exact = true; // a boolean variable that is declared private in order to be accessed by different methods
      private double change, cashTendered;
      private static int cashAmount;
      private static Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in); // private static declared Scanner which allows the user to input characters or strings by different methods
      private JLabel lblUsername, lblPassword;
    private JTextField txtUsername;
    private JPasswordField txtPassword;
    private JButton btnLogin, btnCancel;



public mangInasaldef() {

      boolean repeatLoop = true;

        System.out.print("\nInput Customer Name: ");
        String customerName = inp.nextLine();
        customername = customerName;
        System.out.print("\nInput Cashier Name: ");
        String user = inp.nextLine();
        username = user;
     do{
        System.out.print("\nInput either Dine In or Take Out: ");
        String dInDOut = inp.nextLine();
        dineOut = dInDOut;
            if (dineOut.equals("Dine In") || dineOut.equals("Take Out")){
             System.out.print("");
             repeatLoop = false;
             }
            else{
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try again! Please input Dine In or Take Out only!","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                 repeatLoop = true;
                 System.out.print ("\f");
                }
     }while(repeatLoop);

        System.out.print("\n\n\t\tCashier: " +username);
        System.out.print("                          "+dineOut);
        System.out.print("\n\t\tCustomer Name: " +customername);


    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            new mangInasaldef();
        }
    });
}

public mangInasaldef() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mang Inasal Ordering System");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    String choices[] = {"Paborito Meal 1 Paa","Paborito Meal 1.5 (Spicy Paa with Thigh part)","Paborito Meal 2 (Pecho)","Paborito Meal 3 (Pork Barbeque 4 pcs)","Paborito Meal 4 (Bangus Sisig)","Paborito Meal 5 (Pork Sisig)","Paborito Meal 6 (Bangus Inihaw)","Sulit Meal 1 (Paa)","Sulit Meal 2 (Pork Barbeque 2 pcs)","Pancit Bihon","Dinuguan at Puto","Ensaladang Talong","Softdrinks","Iced Tea","HaloHalo","Leche Flan","Turon Split","Print Receipt"};
    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(choices);
    combo.setBackground(Color.black);
    combo.setForeground(Color.yellow);
    panel.add(combo);
    frame.add(panel); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(350,100);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener () {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            String item = (String)e.getItem();
            if (e.getStateChange () == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            {
                System.out.print("\nYou chose " +item);
                    if (item.equals("Paborito Meal 1 Paa"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of PM1");

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total = bilang * 99;
                        order =  " " + bilang + " " + " PM1 PAA W/ RICE" +"                     "+ total + ".00V" + "\n"; //stores the values of the variables bilang and total in the variable order and prints them

                    }
                     if (item.equals("Paborito Meal 1.5 (Spicy Paa with Thigh part)"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of PM1.5"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        totalSpicy = bilang * 99;
                        order1 =  " " + bilang + " " + " PM1.5 PAA" +"                           "+ totalSpicy + ".00V" + "\n"; //stores the values of the variables bilang and total in the variable order and prints them

                    }
                    if (item.equals("Paborito Meal 2 (Pecho)"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of PM2"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total1 = bilang * 99;
                        order2 =  " " + bilang + " " + " PM2 PECHO W/ RICE" +"                   "+ total1 + ".00V" + "\n";

                    }
                    if (item.equals("Paborito Meal 3 (Pork Barbeque 4 pcs)"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of PM3"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total2 = bilang * 99;
                        order3 =  " " + bilang + " " + " PM3 PORK BBQ W/ RICE " +"               "+ total2 + ".00V" + "\n";

                    }
                    if (item.equals("Paborito Meal 4 (Bangus Sisig)"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of PM4"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total3 = bilang * 99;
                        order4 =  " " + bilang + " " + " PM4 BANGUS SISIG " +"                   "+ total3 + ".00V" + "\n";

                    }
                    if (item.equals("Paborito Meal 5 (Pork Sisig)"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of PM5"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total4 = bilang * 99;
                        order5 =  " " + bilang + " " + " PM5 PORK SISIG " +"                     "+ total4 + ".00V" + "\n";

                    }
                    if (item.equals("Paborito Meal 6 (Bangus Inihaw)"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of PM6"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total5 = bilang * 99;
                        order6 =  " " + bilang + " " + " PM6 BANGUS INIHAW " +"                  "+ total5 + ".00V" + "\n";

                    }
                    if (item.equals("Sulit Meal 1 (Paa)"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of SM1"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total6 = bilang * 59;
                        order7 =  " " + bilang + " " + " SM1 PAA " +"                            "+ total6 + ".00V" + "\n";

                    }
                    if (item.equals("Sulit Meal 2 (Pork Barbeque 2 pcs)"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of SM2"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total7 = bilang * 59;
                        order8 =  " " + bilang + " " + " SM2 PORK BBQ 2 " +"                     "+ total7 + ".00V" + "\n";

                    }
                    if (item.equals("Pancit Bihon"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of Pancit Bihon"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total8 = bilang * 49;
                        order9 =  " " + bilang + " " + " Pancit Bihon " +"                       "+ total8 + ".00V" + "\n";

                    }
                    if (item.equals("Dinuguan at Puto"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of Dinuguan"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total9 = bilang * 49;
                        order10 =  " " + bilang + " " + " Dinuguan at Puto " +"                   "+ total9 + ".00V" + "\n";

                    }
                    if (item.equals("Ensaladang Talong"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of Ensaladang Talong"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total10 = bilang * 29;
                        order12 =  " " + bilang + " " + " Ensaladang Talong " +"                  "+ total10 + ".00V" + "\n";

                    }
                    if (item.equals("Softdrinks"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of Softdrinks"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total11 = bilang * 25;
                        order13 =  " " + bilang + " " + " Softdrinks " +"                         "+ total11 + ".00V" + "\n";

                    }
                    if (item.equals("Iced Tea"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of Iced Tea"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total12 = bilang * 25;
                        order14 =  " " + bilang + " " + " Iced Tea " +"                           "+ total12 + ".00V" + "\n";

                    }
                    if (item.equals("HaloHalo"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of HaloHalo"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total13 = bilang * 49;
                        order15 =  " " + bilang + " " + " HaloHalo " +"                           "+ total13 + ".00V" + "\n";

                    }
                    if (item.equals("Leche Flan"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of Leche Flan"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total14 = bilang * 29;
                        order16 =  " " + bilang + " " + " Leche Flan " +"                         "+ total14 + ".00V" + "\n";

                    }
                    if (item.equals("Turon Split"))
                    {
            Object val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input quantity of Turon Split"); 
            System.out.print(val);

                        Integer bilang= Integer.valueOf((String)val);
                        total15 = bilang * 39;
                        order17 =  " " + bilang + " " + " Turon Split " +"                        "+ total15 + ".00V";

                    }
                    if (item.equals("Print Receipt")) // if Print Receipt was selected it will go to the method computeReceipt
                    {
                        System.out.print("\f"); // clears the screen
                        computeReceipt();
                    }


            }
    }
    });
    }

    public void computeReceipt() {
        totalOrder = total + totalSpicy + total1 + total2 + total3 + total4 + total5 + total6 + total7 + total8 + total9 + total10 + total11 + total12 + total13 + total14 + total15;
        vatCollected = totalOrder * 0.12;
        exact = true;

        do{ 
        System.out.print("\n\n\tYour total bill is: "+totalOrder);
        exact = false;

        Object cashMo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input here your cash");
            System.out.println(cashMo);
                        cashAmount = Integer.valueOf((String)cashMo);
        exact = false;
        change = cashAmount - totalOrder;
            if (cashAmount < totalOrder) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try again. Please enter sufficient money to proceed.","Invalid Input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);   
            exact = true; 
            }
        }while(exact);
        System.out.print("\f");
        etoPoeReceipt();
    }


    public void etoPoeReceipt() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date(); 


        System.out.print("\n                 MANG INASAL");
        System.out.print("\n             BLUMENTRITT BRANCH");
        System.out.print("\n         #1631-1633 BLUMENTRITT ST.,");
        System.out.print("\n            STA CRUZ. MANILA 0000");
        System.out.print("\n               (932) 885-5844");
        System.out.print("\n             Operated by: R L YU");
        System.out.print("\n             TIN 202-161-017-000 VAT");
        System.out.print("\n         ACC. NO.: 050-204079836-000019");
        System.out.print("\n             Tel. #: (02)493-6801");
        System.out.print("\n\n Cashier: " +username);
        System.out.print("                    STATION: 2");
        System.out.print("\n ---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print("\n O.R #: 84486");
        System.out.print("                          "+dineOut);
        System.out.print("\n Customer Name: " +customername);
        System.out.print("                       24");
        System.out.print("\n ---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print("\n                   >>SETTLED<<\n");
        System.out.print(""+order );
        System.out.print(""+order1 );
        System.out.print(""+order2 );
        System.out.print(""+order3 );
        System.out.print(""+order4 );
        System.out.print(""+order5 );
        System.out.print(""+order6 );
        System.out.print(""+order7 );
        System.out.print(""+order8 );
        System.out.print(""+order9 );
        System.out.print(""+order10 );
        System.out.print(""+order11 );
        System.out.print(""+order12 );
        System.out.print(""+order13 );
        System.out.print(""+order14 );
        System.out.print(""+order15 );
        System.out.print(""+order16 );
        System.out.print(""+order17 );
        System.out.print("\n\n SUB TOTAL:                             "+totalOrder+ ".00");
        System.out.print("\n DELIVERY VAT:                            0.00");
        System.out.print("\n                                        ======");
        System.out.print("\n AMOUNT DUE:                            "+totalOrder+ ".00\n\n");
        System.out.printf(" VAT COLLECTED                          %.2f",vatCollected); // declares that the variable should be in two decimal places. % is called format specifier and f is the converter
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print(" CASH Tendered:                         "+cashAmount+ ".00");
        System.out.print("\n                                        ======");
        System.out.printf("\n CHANGE:                                %.2f",change);
        System.out.print("\n               >>Ticket #: 62<<");
        System.out.print("\n       Created:  ");
        System.out.print(dateFormat.format(date));
        System.out.print("\n       SETTLED:  ");
        System.out.print(dateFormat.format(date));
        System.out.print("\n\n *********************************************");
        System.out.print("\n THIS SERVES AS AN OFFICIAL RECEIPT.");
        System.out.print("\n\n For Feedback: TEXT MIO467(Comments/ Suggest");
        System.out.print("\n ions)  and  SEND  to  0917-5941111 or CALL US");
        System.out.print("\n at 0917-5596258");
        System.out.print("\n Email: feedback@manginasal.com");
        System.out.print("\n\n      THANK YOU FOR DINING WITH US!");
        System.out.print("\n\n *********************************************");
        System.out.print("\n S/N: 120416ASL03/1105-6105-9230");
        System.out.print("\n DT S/N: 41-L6971 (P0S1)");
        System.out.print("\n PERMIT NO: 0412-031-125295-000");
        System.out.print("\n MIN: 120276752");

    }





}
```

After the login class was successfully accessed, it does not continue to the main method. I don't know what codes are needed to manipulate to connect the login class to the main class. Thanks for those who will help! :)

Comment: I think your looking at it slightly backwards.  The Login class contains the main method, so within that main method you need to create an instance of the main class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Both the login class and main class needeed to have a main method in order for them to work. There's a code in the login class in which it will call the main class if the username and password is correct. Before the main class will appear, the login class will dispose first. I don't know how to manipulate the codes to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the main method from you login class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            MILogin milogin = new MILogin();
            milogin.run();

}
```

Then instance the MILogin class from your Main Class:

```
MILogin milogin = new MILogin();
milogin.run();
```